Do Java 17 value-based classes allocate instances in the heap?
I’m looking for any trick to reduce pressure on the heap for simple dates, without time and time zone. I wrote a class that interpreted integers as dates using static methods, for Java 8. Now I’m moving that code to Java 17, and tried to use a value-based class for clarity, but it seems as instances are heap-allocated, even when the benchmark uses instances that do not escape the method scope (so, in theory, escape analysis should optimise allocation).
By the ways, I followed all recomendations: no accessible constructor, value-based equals, hashCode and toString implementations, no synchronization, no serialization and a single primitive final instance field.

"it depends". Like so many other things in the JDK, this'll depend heavily on how you use them, what the JVM you run on has implemented and about a dozen other things. For example, if the objects are long-lived and referenced by other objects, then odds are they will have to be allocated on the heap. Short-lived objects that are only passed to other methods that end up being inlined might not get instanciated anywhere at all (and instead "destructed" into a number of registers at runtime). I'm also under the impression that many of those optimizations are yet to come (at least as of JDK 17).

" but it seems as instances are heap-allocated" what are you using to verify this?

The definition of “value based” of Java 8 and even of Java 21 do not differ in saying that “Some classes … are value-based”. It doesn’t say that “you can create value-based classes”. Not that it matters much in practice as there is no special treatment by the JVM yet. Object allocations may get eliminated or not. We don’t know enough about your setup to tell you anything more.

Besides that, having a date that consists of “a single primitive final instance field” sounds much like you actually have an instance. But even if it is an actual date, such a class already exist. And these existing classes are already “value based classes”.

Also, LocalDateTime is a value-based class. Based on the JEP 401 it seems like what you're asking is specifically something they did not include.

@matt: -verbose:gc. I'll try LocalDateTime, thanks.

In Java EVERY Object is allocated on the heap. The only items on the stack are the link to the previous stack-frame, primitive values and the "pointers" to objects (references) used in that method.
The referenced objects in turn are allocate on the heap - every new-statement allocates heap rather than stack-memory.
In your approach via the static methods even your integers end up somewhere in the heap as soon as you transfer the integer values to objects of your business-logic.

This is not entirely true, the JIT may do escape-analysis and instead allocate an object on the stack, see for example Eligibility for escape analysis / stack allocation with Java 7

It’s true that every object is allocated on the heap, by definition, if it is allocated. But we have to separate the formal behavior from implementation details. The question is about the implementation details, so while the answer’s statement is formally true, it does not answer the question.

I don't think that developers should depend on JIT- and JRE-implementation-details since that might harm the compatibility.
